# Entity Framework Table Naming Convention

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, naming-conventions

I am new to Entity Framework. I am currently doing a project in ASP.NET, Crystal Reports and LINQ to SQL.

I have the following tables on the database and I created my DBML from the database

1. City
2. City_Staff
3. City_Program_Contact
4. City_Official
5. Comprehensive_Service

This didn't error out. I just realized the DBML creates Class(Objects) and I am wondering whether this is a correct naming convention for the tables.

It could be great if you can let me know about SQL Server table naming convention and also correct naming convention in Entity Framework.

Comment: Are you referring to what case should be used, or prefixes / suffixes?  Generally, as pointed out by Wahid, underscores are not used.  I think prefixes and suffixes are unnecessary.  Or are you asking about the actual names?  If that is the case, some more information is needed about what data the tables contain.

Comment: I used underscores on my initial design and now I have removed it. Just debating about plural names. Thanks @cadrell0!

Comment: That sort of naming convention choice is pretty subjective, and not really a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I'm not a big fan of using "_" in the naming. I use UpperCamelCase instead.

**For Tables :**

I advice you to use **Plural** in all Entities tables:

- Cities
- CityStaffs

And if the table is just representing many to many relation and has no other fields then I name it as two **Singular** parts :

- CityUser

That will represent these **classes** after mapping in EF :

- City
- CityStaff

And in the City class you'll have `Users` property

Comment: Thanks @Wahid Bitar - I removed the underscore and now thinking about singular vs plural. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
TblTeachers , TblStudents
```

I am thinking of putting it as

```
TeachersTbl , StudentsTbl
```

The Intellisense has other classes which looks like these table names, for filtering them out easily, I use Tbl in the naming.